# Dynamic group by in a MySql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, dynamicquery

I have an `employees` table which has fields like `Name, Salary, City, Country, Department`. I also have a user input where user can select multiple column headers e.g. City, Country etc. from my employees table. I need to make a dynamic query that groups-by all the fields the user has selected, and returns the result. E.g. Sum of all salaries by city, sum of all salaries by country, sum of all salaries by department by country etc.

Here is what I am doing - ('$a' is the variable I get from the dropdown).

```
SELECT
     sum(salary) as sum_salary,
     IF(LOCATE('department', '$a$') > 0, department, NULL)  as 'department',
     IF(LOCATE('city','$a$') > 0, city , NULL)  as 'city'
     IF(LOCATE('country','$a$') > 0, country , NULL)  as 'country'
from tbl_employees
GROUP BY
     IF(LOCATE('department', '$a$') > 0, department, NULL)  as 'department',
     IF(LOCATE('city','$a$') > 0, city , NULL)  as 'city'
     IF(LOCATE('country','$a$') > 0, country , NULL)  as 'country'
LIMIT 10000
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
NAME | SALARY | CITY | COUNTRY| DEPARTMENT
n1     50       Chi    US       Design
n2     100      Chi    US       Product
n3     500      SF     US       Engg
n5     20       SF     US       Engg
n1     200      SF     US       Product
```

If '$a' = 'city', here is what I want

```
   SUM(SALARY) |   CITY
   150             Chi
   720              SF
```

Here is what I get

```
   SUM(SALARY) |   CITY  | COUNTRY  | DEPARTMENT
   150             Chi     NULL       NULL
   720              SF     NULL       NULL
```

The problem with this is if the user has selected only `city` as the group-by column, then I also see the `department` and `country` columns with all NULL values. How do I remove the completely NULL columns. Is this the right way to achieve this? And how can I remove the columns that completely have NULL values. Thanks!

JS Fiddle - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cy7swwpphFSNssHPpZgKtH/1

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done, thanks!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry - thanks, here is the fiddle - all I want to achieve is dynamic group by based on a string - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cy7swwpphFSNssHPpZgKtH/1

Comment: That's not much of a fiddle :-(

Comment: My bad, I thought it was auto save, please try the new link,

Answer (score 0):

Use a Case statement to select the required field. then use a reference to the first column, 1 in group by

```
 SELECT
         case when LOCATE('department', '$a$') > 0 then department
              when LOCATE('city','$a$') > 0 then city
              when LOCATE('country','$a$') > 0 then country
         else Null
         end as field,
         sum(salary) as sum_salary,
    from tbl_employees
    GROUP BY 1    
    LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if user has selected multiple group bys - e.g. department and country?

Comment: i assumed only one field was required in the output before expected output was added to the question. I will update the answer if i can figure something for output with multiple fields

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless